# How to have a substate fill the parent state multiple views with Angular UI Router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I would like to have a `root` state with 2 named views and many substates. The scenario is like having an user `root` state with `root.profile`, `root.password`, etc.

Then i want each substate to fill the named views with its own content, something like this image, being the blue area hardcoded in index.html, and the yellow areas 2 named views, say `'main'` and `'right'`

[image]

I'm linking a plunker where the views are named `main` and `right`, with a `root` state and a `root.substate` substate.

[plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/9oFG9ULFncK2qHUrSpLP?p=preview)

How would you fill the code to make it work?

**Please note:** I know there are **alternative** solutions to this problem, but i am actually asking if this can be achieved the way i just described.

**Please note:** just ignore the breadcrumb area in the picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

forked plunk:
http://plnkr.co/edit/CnXIF4V1Bfdl1ndeFfNb?p=preview

- Each ui-view is named, or unnamed.  `<div ui-view="name">` or `<div ui-view>`
- Unnamed ui-views are actually named "" (empty-string), i.e., `<div ui-view="">`
- You target a named view from a substate by using 'viewname@state' in the view declaration.
- The state to use in that targetting is the state which has the ui-view in its template.

Your index.html is the template for the implicit root state, the state which is called "" (empty-string). Your 'root' state is actually a substate of the real root state.  For this reason, I renamed your 'root' state to 'top' in my plunk.

To target a ui-view in the implicit root state, you would use "viewname@state", where state is the empty string.  So targetting main is done using `"main@"` and targetting right is done using `"right@"`.